# Are the weight spaces of indecomposable $U_q\mathfrak{sl}(2)$-modules at most 2-dimensional?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

This is a follow up of [*this question*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239893/what-are-the-indecomposable-u-q-mathfraksl2-modules).

Let $U_q\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ be Lusztig's integral form of the quantized enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, specialised at $q$ a root of unity. This is an algebra generated by elements $E,F,K$, and by the divided powers of $E$ and $F$. Let $\mathcal O$ be its category of finite dimensional (type $I$, integrable) representations.

> Is it true that every indecomposable object $M\in\mathcal O$ has weight spaces that are at most $2$-dimensional?

(I know that this is true for tilting modules.)